# Как сохранить созданные объекты в игре в Unity? Помогите пожалуйста уже пол года ломаю голову.!

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, save

Мне надо что-бы при спауни объектов(ну или по другому Prefab) они сохранялись при нажатие на кнопку или выхода из игры, и также появлялся при входе в игру или по нажатие кнопки. Помогите пожалуйста уже пол года ломаю голову.!!

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Координаты объекта можно записывать в PlayerPrefs

Comment: хорошо я создал объект и сохранил его координаты а потом перезагрузил игру, координаты сохранил а самого объекта нету

Comment: При выходе из приложения (например в OnApplicationQuit()) можно сохранять координаты в PlayerPrefs, но тогда при запуске игры в Start нужно этот объект спавнить заново Instantiate'ом на заданных координатах.

Comment: А как объект будет понимать что это его координата?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Вы же сохраняете позицию в определенную переменную. И загружаете из нее же. Судя по вопросу - у вас только 1 объект.

Comment: ой это я дурак, не так написал нет у меня будет много объектов

Comment: Отредактируйте тогда вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейший вариант - сохранять позиции всех объектов в массив. После чего при запуске игры спавнить их заново:

```
public struct myVector3 {
    int x, int y, int z
}
[SerializeField] public List<myVector3> ObjectsPositions = new List<myVector3>();

Start () {
    ObjectsPositions = Load();

    foreach (var pos in ObjectsPositions) {
        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

OnApplicationQuit () {
    foreach (var obj in [объекты, который нужно сохранять]) {
        ObjectsPositions.Add(obj);
    }

    Save(ObjectsPositions);
}
```

Сериализовывать эту структуры вы можете как хотите. Например, в JSON или BinarySerialize. Свою структуру myVector3, поэтому что обычный Vector3 не сериализуется.

```
List<myVector3> Load () {
    return [десериализуем оттуда, куда сериализуем в методе Save]
}

void Save (List<myVector3> positions) {
    [сериализуем positions туда, откуда позже будем десериализовывать методом Load()]
}
```